# Problem about ring and integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Assume we have ring $\langle  \{5x|x \in I  \}, +,\cdot \rangle$, $I$ is integers set, $+$ and $\cdot $ is common plus and times.

The ring is not integral domain, because it doesn't contain multiplication identity element.

Why?

Comment: If someone calls this a ring, despite not having $1$, they should be consistent and call it an integral domain too.  [Note: this is a minority view.]

Comment: @vadim123 Maybe it should be "doman," following the same pattern as "rng" :)

Comment: Then instead of semigroups we could have monods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an identity is a nonzero element satisfying $1^2=1$, and there are no such elements in that rng.

In general, in any domain without zero divisors and with identity, the equation $x^2=x$ can only have two solutions since $x(x-1)=0$ implies $x=0$ or $x=1$. Your subring can't provide any more solutions than $\Bbb Z$ already does, being a subset of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This problem is really queer, I admit. :)